# 13.04 - Logon screen frozen

Tags: updates, 13.04, freeze

I am very new with Ubuntu, been a Windows user since the beginning.

Yesterday I did a recommended software update on my laptop running Ubuntu 13.04, upon restarting I can't login at all. The login screen appears, I can move my mouse around but I can't click anywhere to login, not my username, not on the power button in the top corner of the screen, nowhere.

I installed Gnome 3.8 as a shell and everything was going fine, I guess, until I did the update. One thing though, while it was updating, a message appeared saying that some updates couldn't be applied due to some components that were not downloaded properly.

Is there a way to repair Ubuntu or do I have to re-install everything from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to repair it from the console, using the command line.

When the computer is powering on, press the shift key, it should show you the grub menu (if you are dual booting this menu will appear without needing to press shift), it looks like this:

[image]

Select, using the cursor to move the highlighted row and enter to select it, the option labeled 'recovery mode'. It's usually the second option.

The computer will boot into this screen:

[image]

**Firstly enable networking by selecting the "network" row.**

Then select the root option.

Now type these commands, followed by intro, one by one.

```
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

This will do the same as updating from the GUI and hopefully recover the error.

When it's done, type

```
reboot
```

The computer should reboot into normal mode.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'll try this as soon as I get home.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but even through the Recovery Menu I couldn't do anything - my keyboard wasn't working and I couldn't choose any entry.
In the end I solved the problem by booting into a previous Kernel and from there updating my System, after that I could reboot into the new Kernel and everything was working again.