# 13.04 Hangs on the login screen

Tags: 13.04, login

My system boots up as far as the login screen and then hangs just after it reaches it.

It doesn't freeze immediately, I can still move the mouse cursor for a second or two before it locks up. It does freeze before it loads my login screen image though. It just displays the standard purple background with the white dots instead.

Restarting just throws up the same problem again.

I'm running stock 13.04, I update whenever the systems suggests I do so I should be running the latest updates. I believe I do have the proprietary graphics drivers (Radeon HD 7000) installed. I also elected to encrypt the harddrive when I installed Ubuntu orignally (not sure If that has any bearing on things). Everything had been running fine until now.

I tried using the answer from [13.04 - Logon screen frozen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293138/13-04-logon-screen-frozen). When I select "Network" it prompts me with "Continuing with remount your / filesystem in read/write mode and mount any other filesystems defined in /etc/fstab", I click "Yes" and it outputs some text and then freezes forever

I'm not sure if that's related to my login woes or random weirdness. Regardless, here's the output when I click Network:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: clean, 296562/182624256 files, 419034331/730468352   blocks/dev/sda2
   was no cleanly unmounted, check forces.
/dev/sda2: 272/124992 files (4.0% non-contiguous), 140324/249856 blocks
mountall: fsck /boot [991] terminated with status 1
```

Answer (score 1):

check out this page:http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=124775  The interesting part is at the bottom.  His answer requires a live cd or usb of 13.04 for booting purposes and to run the fsck command on the drive in question.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to run fsck using the page you provided and the instructions from http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-centos-rhel-fedora-debian-fsck-ext3-on-luks-volume/ (for dealing with my encrypted volume). It picked up and fixes two errors. Unfortunately Ubuntu is still locking up on the login screen